# What might cause a sudden voltage drop in an airborne drone's battery?

Tags: voltage, batteries, drone

DJI Mavic 2 Zoom Enterprise Drone

We lost connectivity between our handheld controller and drone while flying a drone photogrammetry mission. Photogrammetry missions allow you to pre-program a flight over a specific path or area then, when ready to actually fly, the drone executes the mission autonomously without need to control the drone by hand. After losing connectivity during flight we had to hunt for the drone which we found tangled in branches of a bush a few feet off the ground. The mission was programmed to fly at 100 feet above ground so, some type of failure must have occurred as it crashed at a little over one minute's time of the scheduled 14 minute flight.

The included image is a portion of the flight data and shows the voltage of each cell of the drone battery (4 cells in one battery - One battery per drone) over the portion of time it actually flew the mission. You will see at 00:01:14 a severe drone battery voltage drop which is also when the drone went down.

What we're trying to determine is: Would immediately stopping all 4 drone propellers including their related motors cause a battery voltage drop as shown in the provided image?

- If so, we may conclude the drone hit tree branches, stopped the propellers and fell into the bush.
- If not, we may conclude the battery voltage drop itself caused the drone to fall and end up in the bush, yet still not know what caused the voltage drop.

PS - the trees in that area are not taller than 75 feet.

[image]

Comment: First rule of troubleshooting in electronics: #1 Did you connect the power? #2 Are the connectors a problem?

Comment: In addition to other thoughts here, what's the history for this drone? If this isn't its first flight, then you should have lots of recorded data from earlier flights with which to compare voltage profiles. Altitudes, too. If it is the first flight, probably should add that fact to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like cell blue (or its connections) was/were weak and failed, and the controller attempted but failed to keep the drone aloft by drawing maximum current from the remaining three. Blue voltage may actually have gone negative and telemetry limitations are masking that. The more the voltage drop on the other three cells the larger the difference between them and blue. The cells are in series, of course, so the available voltage is the sum of the four plots you have.

After that it's less clear, maybe it hit the trees and shut down, resulting in less draw and the cell voltages recovered with just standby current.

One would expect stopping the motors (by command, not by physically interfering with the rotors) would cause cell voltages to increase. Physically stalling the rotors would cause cell voltages to decrease as the controller tries to compensate (though it probably gives up at some point and shuts down).

If you can overlay a plot of altitude vs. battery voltage you should be able to tell more about what caused what.

Comment: @Audioguru your comment belongs at the question, not at an answer. please move it